# Get ENUM values from column definition of entity field

Tags: php, symfony, enums, doctrine-orm

I have a column which is defined as ENUM type in a entity class.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('Male', 'Female')")
 */
private $gender;
```

I'm trying to get the ENUM fields by providing the name of the field to **getClassMetadata()** like,

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata('App\Entity\User');
$fieldMapping = $classMetadata->getFieldMapping($field);
```

This **$fieldMapping** has all the necessary field related data. When I try to access the **columnDefinition** of this field by **$fieldMapping['columnDefinition']**, it returns just the **string**.

```
string 'ENUM('Male', 'Female')' (length=22)
```

Is it possible to get the values in array like,

```
[
    [0] => 'Male',
    [1] => 'Female'
]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a custom enum type as described in Doctrine documentation [Mysql Enums](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-2-defining-a-type):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DBAL;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class EnumGender extends Type
{
    const MALE = 'male';
    const FEMALE = 'female';

    const NAME = 'enum_gender';
    const VALUES = array(self::MALE, self::FEMALE);

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $values = array_map(function ($val) {
            return "'" . $val . "'";
        }, self::VALUES);

        return 'ENUM(' . implode(', ', $values) . ')';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (!\in_array($value, self::VALUES)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid '" . self::NAME . "' value.");
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your entity you can change the property annotation to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", type="enum_gender")
 */
private $gender;
```

To finish you can do the following trick in order to get the custom enum class where are defined your values (I admit it is ugly, but I haven't found an other way to do it properly):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(User::class);
$fieldMapping = $classMetadata->getTypeOfField('gender');
$className = implode('', explode('_', ucwords($fieldType, '_')));
$namespace = 'AppBundle\DBAL\\' . $className;
$values = $namespace::VALUES;
```